# excel-vba playable maze making cells(interpret as walls) to be objects that cannot be passed through

Tags: excel, vba

so i made form control buttons for offset.select  (the up down left right buttons) and i cant figure out a code that when a cell is surrounded by a wall(i made it be a black-filled cell), the cell can only go to its left/right/etc. your help is very much appreciated (i would consider my skill in excel-vba as a novice)

[image: here's what my maze looks like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following in your worksheets VBA code and you can even walk through the maze with your arrow keys. You will not be able to go through walls.

```
Option Explicit

Public OldPosition As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If OldPosition Is Nothing Then Set OldPosition = Target.Parent.Range("AF9") 'adjust AF9 to your start position

    If Target.Interior.Color = vbBlack Or Target.Row = 1 Or Target.Column = 1 Or Intersect(Target, OldPosition.Offset(-1, -1).Resize(3, 3)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        OldPosition.Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
        OldPosition.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        Set OldPosition = Target
        OldPosition.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("V50")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "you finished"
    End If
End Sub
```

**How does it work?**

- We use a public variable to save the current position of the selected cell.
- The Worksheet_SelectionChange Event triggers everytime the selected cell changes. So we check if the background color of the target cell `Target.Interior.Color` is black. If so then we go back to the old position `OldPosition.Select` otherwise we accept and remember the target cell as our current position `Set OldPosition = Target`

This is to prevent the user from jumping with the mouse

```
If Target.Interior.Color = vbBlack Or Intersect(Target, OldPosition.Offset(-1, -1).Resize(3, 3)) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: you're a beast man thank you so much :DD oh one last question, im trying to make a code that when i finished the maze(if i go to cell V50) a pop up msg would appear and say "congrats" or something like that; i cant put into words the if then statement i want to say,, or if it's supposed to be an if then statement in the code.

Comment: Added a prevention of jumping with the mouse.

Comment: the `OldPosition.Interior.Pattern = xlNone` gets highlighted and there's an error saying that "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: the jumping with the mouse prevention gets highlighted as well saying the run-time error 91

Comment: Ok I improved the initialization and prevented the user to jump into row/column 1 to prevent the errors. See edit.

Comment: `    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("V50")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "you finished"
        Range("AF9").Select
    End If`  

i tried to make this so that when the game is finished, it will go back to AF9, which is the starting line, and it doesnt seem to work?

Comment: @KurtCinco you need to `Application.EnableEvents = False/True` before/after using `.Select` to prevent `.Select` triggering the SelectionChange event again otherwise the event prevents jumping ;) and moving from end to start is jumping ;)

Comment: noted. so the `.select` did work; it went to AF9, however when i click my buttons again, the active cell(which is AF9) went to V50 again

Comment: @KurtCinco If you change position you must also tell him that that is your actual position now. So the OldPosition needs to be updated too `Set OldPosition = Target.Parent.Range("AF9")`

Comment: Ohh :O okayokay im done with the code thank you so much!